# What is fully qualified service name for a service in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio

I have a service running in namespace istio-system , I want to connect it with pod in different namespace say default . My cluster is running on minikube . How to do the same ?
I tried myService.istio-system.svc.cluster.local , but it didnot worked and from where its picking this i.e from which configuration file . I know in normal k8 cluster but not in minikube
Any help would be appreciated

#### Added by BMW

The user in fact is asking a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Here is the real question, he put in comment.

I want to make use of kubectl port forwarding technique to forward traffic from external world to service running inside minikube so that I can access it from outside I am trying below command :

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local 31000 31000 
Error from server (NotFound): services "kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local" not found
```

Comment: Can you resolve the name from the pod? Note: ping will not work, you’ll have to use curl.

Comment: Does "myService.istio-system" alone work?

Comment: I want to make use of kubectl port forwarding technique to forward traffic from external world to service running inside minikube so that I can access it from outside I am trying below command :kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local 31000 31000
Error from server (NotFound): services "kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local" not found

Comment: No it did not works

Comment: This is classic case of [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali 31000:31000 -n istio-system`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked a bit different in my case , we have to explicitly specify namespace (Not Using fully qualified Domain name ) . I got help from below post
https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/accessing-services-from-the-outside/
Thanks everyone for help

```
kubectl port-forward -n istio-system --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local 31000 31000
```

Comment: So `port-forward` is different, in your case, you don't need care of the domain name. this command should work with short type: `kubectl port-forward -n istio-system  --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali 31000 31000 `, because you have nominated the namespace with `-n istio-system` no need repeat it again in service name

Answer (score 9):

Realized the user is asking [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

I put the answer here:

```
kubectl -n istio-system port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali 31000 31000
```

with `-n istio-system`, you can nominiate the namespace you are working on, and no need care of its domain name postfix.

Here is the original answer, but still useful for some use cases.

Please reference this:[image]

So in your case, if cross namespace, you have to use below names:

```
<service_name>.<namespace>
<service_name>.<namespace>.svc
<service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

svc is for service, pod is for pod.

If you need double check the last two parts, use `CoreDNS` as sample, check its configmap:

```
master $ kubectl -n kube-system get configmap coredns -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-28T11:37:40Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "179"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 0ee90a0b-6c71-4dbf-ac8a-906a5b37ea4f
```

that's the configuration file for CoreDNS, and it is set `cluster.local` as port of full DNS name.

Comment: From where I can get Base Domain Name . I believe its different in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can also use kiali service type to NodePort to expose the service on the minikube host server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-n` option with `kubectl` to port-forward to a service in different namespace.

`kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/kiali 31000:31000 -n istio-system`